# Modules showing as loaded in command line but not in Apache

Tags: php, apache

I am running a Centos server on a local VBOX, and have installed a custom PHP module.

When I run `php -m` from the commmand line, I see the module has been installed.

When I output `phpinfo()` the module is showing as not having been installed.

What can I do to troubleshoot this difference, and to get the module available through `apache`?

Comment: You can always try running `php -r "phpinfo();" > ~/phpinfo.html` from the terminal and then opening the phpinfo.html file in your home directory.  That should include all active modules for PHP and not run through Apache.  You might need to restart apache though, which shouldn't take too long

Comment: command line php and web-based php almost ALWAYS have separate .ini files, and should be treated as separate environments. just because something is loaded in one means absolutely nothing to the other.

Comment: Stopped the machine and re-loaded it a few times and it eventually started to work. Will try the suggestion when I next have to build it as this will likely happen again.

Comment: I removed the Linux/Centos from the title, because they aren't really relevant to the question, then formatted the commands using backticks to get them highlighted inline, and tried to make the actual question a bit more clear.  I hope this helps, though from the comments you may not need this question any more.  If true, can you try to provide information for other people in the future about how you were able to make it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the following:

1. Deleted the modules and settings from the server.
2. Rebooted
3. re-installed the modules and settings, I did make a small change to my php.ini file and I put the direct path to the file in the modules directory. I also added an ini file to the php.d folder.
4. Rebooted

And it worked...